# C#, How to pass property name from string parameter for Dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, linq, dynamic

My API response will return a list of JSON objects and I need to verify the order of the list, so I write a function as follows. But I got a problem for the LINQ order by sentence, it only works when I specify the actual field, but I need pass this field name as a parameter. so something like
 `var expectedList = jObjList.OrderBy(x => x.parameterFieldName.ToString());` 
please give me some suggestions, many thanks.

```
public void VerifyOrderBy(string jsonString, string parameterFieldName)
{
    List<dynamic> jObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(jsonString);
    var expectedList = jObjList.OrderBy(x => x.LastName.ToString());
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedList.SequenceEqual(jObjList));
}
```

the JSON string looks like follows

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "w3pCj",
        "LastName": "mSJOV",
        "IsDeleted": false
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "rMnH7",
        "LastName": "rMnH7",
        "IsDeleted": false
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Jia",
        "LastName": "Yu",
        "IsDeleted": false
    }
]
```

Comment: I believe you can use square brackets.

Comment: It works even with `x.LastName` as well! But to be honest I've tried it in *LinqPad* only

Comment: You mean like this "var expectedList = jObjList.OrderBy(x => x.[parameterFieldName].ToString());", but i got "The name 'ToString' does not exist in the current context." error message.

Comment: @YuJia my mistake man got it clear from your comment to gabor's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`nameof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) operator keyword like this:

```cs
jObjList.OrderBy(x => nameof(x.LastName));
```

**UPDATE #1**

Let's say we have a `Person` class:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say we have a list of people:

```cs
var people =
    JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(
            File.ReadAllText("data.json", Encoding.UTF8)
        );
```

We can have a parameter that will contain the property name we want to order by:

```cs
string parameterName = nameof(Person.LastName); // or simply "LastName"
```

We get a reference to that property:

```cs
PropertyInfo orderByProperty =
    typeof(Person)
        .GetProperties()
        .SingleOrDefault(property => property.Name == parameterName);
```

Now we can order by the selected property:

```cs
var result = people.OrderBy(person => orderByProperty.GetValue(person)).ToList();
```

Please note:

- Of course you should check if the `orderByProperty` is not `null`. :)
- This will work only on in-memory objects (LINQ-to-Objects) but not on a DB set (LINQ-to-SQL, EF)

Do not forget to add the required `using` statement to be able to get the `PropertyInfo`:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
```

**UPDATE #2**

If you have such a simple json structure and you want to use `dynamic` objects for ordering then you can achieve it like this:

```cs
var people =
    JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(
            File.ReadAllText("data.json", Encoding.UTF8)
        );

string parameterName = "LastName";

var result =
    people
        .OrderBy(person =>
        {
            var personObject = person as JObject;
            var propertyValueObject = personObject.GetValue(parameterName) as JValue;

            return propertyValueObject.Value;
        })
        .ToList();
```

Although it works I would prefer UPDATE #1 solution. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I need is how can I pass a string parameter to the LINQ OrderBy clause instead use actual field "LastName"

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation with custom comparer. This allows you to pass any property name:

```
public class JObjComp<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private string _field;

    public JObjComp(string field)
    {
        _field = field;
    }

    int IComparer<T>.Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        //this is bit flimsy but as we know that passed object is 
        //a dynamic, should work
        dynamic aa=(dynamic)a;
        dynamic bb=(dynamic)b;
        return string.Compare(aa[_field].ToString(), bb[_field].ToString());
    }
}
```

Now use our custom comparer:

```
List<dynamic> jObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(jstr);
jObjList.Sort(new JObjComp<dynamic>(field));
```

The list is sorted insitu, so you can assert using `jObjList` itself.